# TanStack table Svelte

Tags: datatable, svelte, tanstack

I am rendering fine another component inside a cell in my table

```
cell: (info) =>
                renderComponent(TokenLogo, {
                    name: info.row.original.name,
                    tokens: [
                        {
                            address: info.row.original.underlying.address,
                            chainId: info.row.original.underlying.chainId,
                        },
                    ],
                    size: "sm",
                }),
```

I am struggling trying to figure out how to render another component inside the same cell. Anyone has an example? Thanks